# Can a collection element reference the collection?

Tags: c#, collections, element

I have a class that arranges in a tree structure by optionally including lists of itself, something like:

```
class MyClass
{
    List<MyClass> MyClassList;
    ...
}
```

Is there any way an element can call its parent collection? Like,

```
class MyClass
{
    List<MyClass> MyClassList;
    ...

    private void AddItemToParentCollection()
    {
        parent.MyClassList.Add(new MyClass());
    }
}
```

I think I could write a function that tells a class where it is in the tree (and so where it's parent is) by traversing the tree until it finds itself, but I'm hoping there's a neater way.

Comment: How is your data structure to represent the tree? Can you post the related code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?  Of course if you pass a reference to the parent into the child the child can call methods on it.

Comment: You need bi-directional association between parent and child (each child should have reference to parent node)

Comment: Thanks all, think I have it now, and some new concepts for the toolbox :)

Comment: It's surprisingly tricky to maintain a parent-child relationship invariant. Some thoughts on it are here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/03/28/why-can-t-i-access-a-protected-member-from-a-derived-class-part-two-why-can-i.aspx and here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/06/08/persistence-facades-and-roslyn-s-red-green-trees.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Node
{
    Node parent;
    List<Node> children = new List<Node>();

    public void Add(Node child)
    {
        if (child.Parent != null)
            // throw exception or call child.Parent.Remove(child)

        children.Add(child);
        child.Parent = this;
    }

    public void Remove(Node child)
    {
        if (child.Parent != this)
           // throw exception

        children.Remove(child);
        child.Parent = null;
    }
}
```

With such structure you can add items to parent collection (not sure it should be responsibility of child node):

```
private void AddItemToParentCollection()
{
    if (Parent == null)
       // throw exception 

    Parent.Add(new Node());
}
```